# Why did Sheridan divorce Lochley, given that both look like decent human beings who are not hard to get along?

Tags: babylon-5

Both characters are highly respectable. They were captains of a station whom people looked up to.

Sheridan was as handsome as Star Trek's Captain Kirk but he was not a womaniser like Kirk. President Sheridan has none of the bad habits of President Kennedy or President Clinton which drove their wives mad. Sheridan was a one-woman man throughout to Delenn. He did not give in easily to sexual temptation when he was seduced once by a Earth political officer. He also seemed like a devoted husband to his second wife, Anna. He seemed like a man of good husband material. He is a trophy husband for any woman who captures his heart.

Lochley is probably the most gorgeous Captain in Science Fiction history. Enough said. Sheridan divorced her after 3 months of marriage. She is a trophy wife for any man who marries her.

Why did they separate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sheridan and Lochley's brief relationship (and subsequent divorce) is described in [B5: Strange Relations](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Strange_Relations). In short, they married in haste and then regretted it almost immediately. They argued for a few months, then got divorced as quickly as they'd gotten together.

> **Lochley:** *We hit it off fell crazy in love, got married realized we'd made a terrible mistake, fell crazy out of love, and split up.
>   You see, in a relationship, you gotta take turns being in charge but
>   we both wanted to be in charge all the time. We had arguments that
>   could peel paint off the wall.*

That they were both were intending to become career military probably didn't help, nor did the fact that they'd started their marriage in the heady atmosphere of having just graduated military academy.